# Passing a bgcolor value as a parameter to TD

Tags: javascript

I am using the following JavaScript code to populate a table. How can I pass the *bgcolor* value as a parameter to TD?

```
    let template = `
        <tr>
           <td bgcolor="#00FF00">${"pump"+child.val().PumpID}</td>
           <td bgcolor="#00FF00">${child.val().StartTime}</td>
           <td bgcolor="#00FF00">${child.val().Duration}</td>
           <td bgcolor="#00FF00">${child.val().GalsPumped}</td>
           <td bgcolor="#00FF00">${child.val().Cycle}</td>
           <td bgcolor="#00FF00">${child.val().Status}</td>
        </tr>`;
        table.innerHTML += template;
      })
    });
```

Basically I want to do this:

```
var  color_variable = #ff00;
.
.
<td bgcolor=color_variable>${child.val().Status}</td>
```

Comment: Hey Sami, what do you mean by pass the bgcolor value as parameter to TD? It seems to me you are already assigning a value to bgcolor in the template, so do you need to be able to set it using a variable? Please explain what you are trying to do here.

Comment: yo mean like `bgcolor="${parameter}"` or `bgcolor="${child.val().BgColor}"` if `child.val()` has one of those

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to modify *bgColor* dynamically by altering the *color_variable*. If you're not using a framework (like [Vue.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vue.js), [React](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(JavaScript_library)), or [Angular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_(web_framework))) and *if* this is the behavior you want you might want to do something like that:

```
let themeOptions = {
    color_variable: 'green'
}

function rerender() {
    let template = `
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="${themeOptions.color_variable}">${"pump" + child.val().PumpID}</td>
            <td bgcolor="${themeOptions.color_variable}">${child.val().StartTime}</td>
            <td bgcolor="${themeOptions.color_variable}">${child.val().Duration}</td>
            <td bgcolor="${themeOptions.color_variable}">${child.val().GalsPumped}</td>
            <td bgcolor="${themeOptions.color_variable}">${child.val().Cycle}</td>
            <td bgcolor="${themeOptions.color_variable}">${child.val().Status}</td>
        </tr>`;
    table.innerHTML += template;
}

function changeColor(color) {
    themeOptions.color_variable = color;
    rerender();
}

changeColor('blue')
```

Of course, this is not the best code sample. You might want to modify it to suit your needs, but you get the idea. You can always use objects to pass a value by reference and modify the value later. **But don't forget that you have to rerender the DOM**.